# Cannot send session cache limiter / Cannot modify header information

Tags: php

I am very new to PHP. Coding my first website.

index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>   
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <form action="authenticate.php" method="post">
     //form inputs
   </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

The form calls authenticate.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

//Authenication work
//...
// line 43 here
if(!$authen){
  include_once("index.php");
}
else{
  header('Location: main.php');
  exit();
}
?>
```

Whenever I run the website and login, as soon as i click on the **submit** button in the form, instead of being redirected to `main.php`, I get redirected in the browser to `authenticate.php`, and I see this :

[image]

Text in image:

```
Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /var/www/html/projet/authenticate.php:1) in /var/www/html/projet/authenticate.php on line 2

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/projet/authenticate.php:1) in /var/www/html/projet/authenticate.php on line 51
```

My `main.php` code (the page I was supposed to be redirected to instead):

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html>
<head>
...
```

Things I have tried so far:

1. Making sure session_start() is at the beginning of every page
2. Trimming EVERY POSSIBLE white space before `<?php` and after `?>`

I am getting desperate. **Please note that the same website and files work locally on wampserver, but when i put them on a server this happened**.

Am I missing something? Sorry I am **completely new to PHP** and I am learning.

Also questions:

1. Do comments in PHP files count as empty spaces?
2. Does Indentation in conditions in PHP files count as empty spaces?

Comment: Did you check the file's encoding as well as the server's default encoding for PHP files? A BOM (byte order mark) can also cause that.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I am editing the files on notepad++ (made sure encoding is `UTF8` and then pushed then using Filezilla. Then i would just Right click Edit The files from the server directly using Notepad. What can i do to investigate further?

Comment: There are 2 types of UTF-8 encoding types. One with BOM and one without. If you didn't specify without the byte order mark, then there's the problem. It should be without BOM.

Comment: If not what I said above, then there may be a hidden unicode somewhere; that too can cause headers to be sent. Use a hex editor and you'll see it.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I noticed when I opened files using Notepad++ that some of them were encoded in UTF-8 BOM, I changed it to UTF-8 , and then I pushed. After that I continued to edit using Notepad.

Comment: There's the problem. You need to save them all again without BOM. Edit: this is covered in [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php?rq=1).

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Great!! Post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: As requested, *cheers*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 types of UTF-8 encoding types. One with BOM (byte order mark) and one without. If you didn't specify *without* the byte order mark, then there's the problem. It should be without BOM.

You need to resave all of your files without it.

References:

- https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

A byte order mark is an invisible set of characters that can also account for output before header.